# Edit vhost port in plesk 10.3

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Someone knows how can I change the vhost listen port in Plesk 10.3 on ubuntu server ?

I can change the apache listen port with this command line :

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -D psa -e'replace into misc (param, val) values ("http_port", <custom http port>)'
```

(source : http://kb.parallels.com/11232) but I don't find How can I change a vhost port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find how to change the vhost port :

`vim /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN.COM/conf/XXXXXXXXX.http.include`

Replace the port 80 by this I want.

Remake the vhost conf 
`/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=<domain_name>` with `<domain_name>` without `www`

Comment: You're wrong.
This config file *XXXXXXXXX.http.include* will be overwritten in a short time, say psa restarted or websrvmng started.